# Throwing exceptions multiple times

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code:

```
    static int GetLastAddedIDHelper(OleDbConnection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            // Init variables.
            OleDbCommand command = null;
            string cmdText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";

            if (connection != null)
                command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
            else
                throw new ArgumentNullException("connection", "The connection was passed as null. Therefore the globally used connection is used but was never set.");

            return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }

    public static int GetLastAddedID()
    {
        try
        {
            return GetLastAddedIDHelper(_Connection);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }

    private void Button_Click_Action()
    {
        try
        {
            int i = AccessDbServiceBase.GetLastAddedID();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ExceptionHandler.GetExceptionMessage(ex));
        }
    }
```

The above code will get the last inserted ID from an Access database for me. Now, to do this, `Button_Click_Action` will call `GetLastAddedID` and that will call `GetLastAddedIDHelper`. When a `exception` occurs in `GetLastAddedIDHelper`, I throw the exception up to the main method `Button_Click_Action`.

I'm wondering if I'm doing this the correct way like, is the throw in `GetLastAddedID` necessary, should I use `throw` instead of `throw ex`, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception handling in `GetLastAddedIDHelper` and `GetLastAddedID` do not serve any useful purpose in this case.  Your intent, it would seem, is to simply catch the exception and then do nothing with it except to rethrow it.  If that is the case then why bother catching it all? Just let the exception propagate up the stack until an exception handler that can handle it gets it, in the `Button_Click_Action` method in this case.

In this example your exception handling is actually harmful because `throw ex` will mess up your stack trace.  You want to use `throw` instead.

Comment: So basically, if the methods `GetLastAddedIDHelper` and `GetLastAddedID` are only used in other methods that will have exception handling it's better to just leave the `try...catch` if throwing is the only thing I do?

Comment: Yep, that is the short of it.  And if you do find yourself in a situation where you need to rethrow (you probably will not being doing this very often but there are some use cases) then use `throw;` to rethrow properly.  You can search for 'C# rethrow' on Google for more details on why.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do `throw;` because `throw ex;` will reset the stack trace.